# Get number of invocations

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

Does MockK provide a way of finding how many times a method has been invoked on a mock object?

I'm looking for something like `Mockito.mockingDetails(mock).getInvocations()`, but for MockK.

I can only find a way of `checking` how many invocations there have been, using `verify()`, but not a way of `getting` the number of invocations.

Comment: https://mockk.io/#capturing may help you.

Comment: @ocos thanks for the pointer. I see that I can capture to a mutable list and then check its size to find the number of invocations. That's a bit indirect, but it works. But only if the function takes arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually store all invocations of a method. There may be an internal helper function to access the invocations.

```kotlin
val invocations = mutableListOf<Invocation>()

val mCar = mockk<Car>()

every { 
    mCar.drive() 
} answers {
    invocations.add(invocation)

    // mocked answer or call the original
    callOriginal()
}

mCar.drive()
mCar.drive()

println(invocations)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. I would also mention for any future readers that making the list thread-safe might be appropriate in certain situations. For example, using `Collections.synchronizedList`.

Comment: So you mean we should handle the counting ourselves? :(